# Why doesn't CTRL+C (simulated with Awt.Robot) work properly?

Tags: java, awtrobot

I have read a web page frame from a browser with a following routine and gain all time a same result (first time copied part of the page):

1. Move a mouse to a frame
2. Select a text with a triple click
3. Copy text with simulated CTRL+C keyboard press event
4. Print copied text
5. Go to step #1 if mouse is still in the frame

For implementation details see code below:

```
final static int TIME_CONST = 10;
final static int STEP_Y = 10;
int x = 100; 
int y = 50;
int count = 0;
Robot robot = new Robot();

while(y < 600) {
    robot.mouseMove(x, y);
    y += STEP_Y;
    Thread.sleep(TIME_CONST); 

    // Select text with triple mouse click
    robot.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK ); 
    robot.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK ); 
    robot.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK ); 
    robot.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
    robot.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK ); 
    robot.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
    Thread.sleep(TIME_CONST);   

    Sequence(robot, 5, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK, KeyEvent.VK_C);
    Thread.sleep(TIME_CONST); 

    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();             
    Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(clipboard);           
    boolean hasTransferableText = (contents != null) && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

    String copyResult = "";
    if(hasTransferableText) {
        copyResult = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    }

    System.out.println("#"+(count++)+": " + copyResult);
}
```

Comment: does the tripple click work? Do you see the text is selected?

Comment: @Fortega The triple click works right (lines become selected). `contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)` returns all time the same object from clipboard. It seems like ` Sequence(robot, 5, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK, KeyEvent.VK_C)` doesn't work like CTRL-C.

Comment: You are right I have to use `KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL` instead of `KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK` in my `Sequence(Robot r, int sleep, int... keyEvents)` method. It works. Please post your approach as an answer, I am going to accept it.

Comment: @Fortega Well done! $)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
instance.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
Thread.sleep(200); 
instance.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C); 
Thread.sleep(200); 
instance.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C); 
Thread.sleep(200); 
instance.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
Thread.sleep(200);
```

KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL instead of KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK